# How I can I move the DT table "search box" to be o the LEFT side of the table - ( table is inside shinydashboard box())?

Tags: search, shinydashboard, dt

Does anyone have a solution on how I can move the "search box" on a DT table to be o the LEFT side and a caption on top? [see image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWtpJ.png). The table is inside a box() element on shinydashboard app. (code below). Thanks!

```
body <- dashboardBody(
 box(width = 6,
            uiOutput ("clicked_country"), 

            div(DT::dataTableOutput("spCountyTable"), 
                                   style  = "overflow-y: auto; height: 460px")))
)


server <- function(input, output, session){

output$spCountyTable <- DT::renderDataTable ({ 

    filtereddata <-subset(county_speciesGroup2,county_speciesGroup2$County_Nm==input$County_Name)}, 

  caption = 'Table 1: This is a simple caption for the table.',
  extensions = c('ColReorder','FixedHeader'),  
  options = list(      
                 paging = FALSE,
                 fixedHeader = TRUE,
                 colReorder = TRUE,
                 order = list(list(1, 'asc'))
  )
}
```

Comment: one idea could to override the existing css with a custom css. If you could you provide a minimal working example it would be easier get quick help.

Answer (score 1):

This is the idea..

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)

ui <- basicPage(

  DT::dataTableOutput("mytable"),

  tags$style(HTML(".dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_length {
                  float: right;}
                  .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_filter {
                  float: left;
                  text-align: left;}"
                  )
            )
    )

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({
  mtcars})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```